# How to insert Insert html context into elastic search?

Tags: html, node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am trying to post html content into elastic search, but elastic search decodes and stores the values in to it? I would not want it to decode. I would like to store html as it is How do we do it?

Comment: Can you show what you store, what you get and what you expect instead?

Comment: I post "body: "<p>After you land your first job out of college, you’re likely going to be <a href="https://www.credit.com/debt/strategies-for-paying-off-student-loan-debt/" target="_blank">paying off student loan debt</a>.</p> " but when its getting stored as "&lt;p&gt;&nbspAfter you land your first job out of college, you’re likely going to be &lt;a href=&doublequote;https://www.credit.com/debt/strategies-for-paying-off-student-loan-debt/" target="_blank"&gt;paying off student loan debt&lt;/a&gt.&lt;p&gt

Comment: Can you update your question with your index settings? `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index`